# Error when building HSL for GHC 8.10.4.20210212

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, haskell, nix-shell

I'm trying to get the haskell language server installed on my mac and I"m following the docs at https://docs.plutus-community.com/docs/setup/editors/prerequisites.html but they seem to not work. My GHC version (in a nix shell) is:

```
11:31AM /Users/paymahn/haskell-language-server nix  ✘ 1 master ✱
 ❯❯❯ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.4.20210212
```

and when I invoke `./cabal-hls-install hls-8.10.4.20210212` I get the following output:

```
Error when running Shake build system:
  at want, called at src/Development/Shake/Internal/Args.hs:83:67 in shk-0.19.6-79b14aaa:Development.Shake.Internal.Args
* Depends on: hls-8.10.4.20210212
  at error, called at src/Development/Shake/Internal/Rules/File.hs:179:58 in shk-0.19.6-79b14aaa:Development.Shake.Internal.Rules.File
* Raised the exception:
Error, file does not exist and no rule available:
  hls-8.10.4.20210212
```

Anyone know what this means and how to fix it?

EDIT: I get the same error if I invoke `stack ./install.hs 8.10.4.20210212`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `stack.yaml` for 8.10.4 was removed which is why this error happens. Checking out tag 1.4.0 fixes it.